# Using Hyper-V on bitlocker to go volume

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, bitlocker

I configured "bitlocker to go" on a volume in external HDD(USB3), and I stored my VM's vhd in that volume.

Although I enabled auto-unlock on the volume, Hyper-V fails to access the vhds.

Hypver-V manager reports: "IDE emulator has no privileages to unlock the drive. Fail to access the vhd."

I find out that bitlocker to go volume is unlocked only the time when the account log-ins, which was used to enable auto-unlock.

Is there any way to **grant privileages to service to unlock encrypted volume**, or another way to auto unlock the encrypted volume?

Because I have limited space on my system drive and no other fixed drive, I want to store my VM's vhd on external HDD.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You are required to be logged into a user in order to unlock a bitlocker volume.  You would have to modify the permissions of the drive to grant access to additional profiles.

Comment: @Ramhound Hyper-V service run by System account: "Local services". and it has permission on the drive. And in case of bitlocker volume, it needs to be unlcoked first. But Local service account has no privileage to unlocking. That is the problem.
I want to know the way to grant the bitlocker privleage to local services.